# How to Make Home-made Flour Tortilla Bowls for Salads?

Tags: frying, flour-tortilla

I have tried a couple ways to do this and they have been OK.  Of course, when I worked in industrial kitchens, using a deep fryer and a stainless steel potato masher (but larger) was ideal, but neither of these tools are available in my home kitchen.

So basically, I have a 12-15 inch flour tortilla I want to make into a fried bowl for a nice salad.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try brushing the tortilla with oil, and baking it upside down over a steel bowl.

Comment: This seems like a good idea.  I will try this.

Answer (score 7):

JustRightMenus touched on this topic in [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5510/how-can-i-make-a-taco-shell/5512#5512) to a similar question.

Quoting that answer:

> you can make your own shell for taco salad by placing a large flour (burrito-size) tortilla in an oven-safe bowl (shaped however you'd like) and putting a big ball of tinfoil inside it. You can also do the opposite - place the bowl upside-down and drape the tortilla over it. Either way, Bake at 350 degrees for 10-15 minutes until it's lightly browned, and you're done! When you remove the tinfoil and the bowl, the tortilla will hold its own shape.

Comment: I do the bake-in-a-bowl version every time I make taco salads. Depending on how crispy you want the shell, just keep an eye on it in the oven.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to fry in oil, then just use a ladle to get the bowl shape you desire. I've done that in the past with good results.

Comment: I have tried this and it works OK, but not as well as I would like...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a posting somewhere that used a muffin pan, putting it upside down and placing smaller tortillas in between the crevices before baking.  They look great, wavy, just like they serve in the restaurants!

Comment: Probably something like this: http://www.emilybites.com/2011/02/mini-taco-bowls.html But don't they look better if you just use the actual muffin cups? http://www.hispanickitchen.com/profiles/blogs/muffin-tin-tacos

Answer (score 1):

I somehow acquired a "tortilla bowl maker" as a gift. It looks something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Norpro-Nonstick-Tortilla-Bowl-Makers/dp/B00005EBH7/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005EBH7). It's essentially a metal mold with ridged sides on the "bowl". We baked flour tortillas on it, but the results were . . . "eh". You may have better luck making bowls from corn tortillas, though.

Comment: Cool!  I have never seen one of those...  Pretty nifty.  I'm sure it would work with one of these other techniques mentioned here...

Answer (score 1):

I brushed both sides with oil and put IN a bowl and microwaved it.  It tasted fried and crispy.

Answer (score 0):

You can order tortilla bowl fryers on line. They are round shaped with ridges & a really long handle for deep frying, just be careful of the size, a 6" was too big for my deep fryer.